# In Go sync.Map why this part of implementation is inconsistent or do I misunderstand something?

Tags: go, implementation, language-implementation

`sync.Map` is a concurrent-safe map implementation. the type of raw maps in `sync.Map` actually is `map[any]*entry`.

When we call `Map.LoadOrStore` and the entry exists, `entry.tryLoadOrStore` is invoked and the following is the code of this function

```golang
func (e *entry) tryLoadOrStore(i any) (actual any, loaded, ok bool) {
    p := e.p.Load()
    if p == expunged {
        return nil, false, false
    }
    if p != nil {
        return *p, true, true
    }

    // Copy the interface after the first load to make this method more amenable
    // to escape analysis: if we hit the "load" path or the entry is expunged, we
    // shouldn't bother heap-allocating.
    ic := i
    for {
        if e.p.CompareAndSwap(nil, &ic) {
            return i, false, true
        }
        p = e.p.Load()
        if p == expunged {
            return nil, false, false
        }
        if p != nil {
            return *p, true, true
        }
    }
}
```

And this is another function `trySwap`, when we call `Swap` or `Store`, this function is also invoked.

```golang
func (e *entry) trySwap(i *any) (*any, bool) {
    for {
        p := e.p.Load()
        if p == expunged {
            return nil, false
        }
        if e.p.CompareAndSwap(p, i) {
            return p, true
        }
    }
}
```

`tryLoadOrStore` can be implemented like `trySwap` just based on its logic but it doesn't. Here is my question: since their logic is similar, why they are not implemented in same way?

when I try to understand, I think its because the difference of parameter type, if `I` is `*any`, it doesn't need to do a copy since it's already a pointer and we does not need to care about the escape analysis. But there seems to be no special reason to get address  from the outer caller.

```golang
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        if v, ok := e.trySwap(&value); ok {
            if v == nil {
                return nil, false
            }
            return *v, true
        }
    }
```

Then I have no idea why this two functions (and other functions) are implemented in different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frirst, [a quote](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/399094/comments/0ac1d74c_d672aae9) from Bryan Mills, the original author of `sync.Map`:

> `sync.Map` is pretty gnarly to begin with!

The code in `sync.Map` is very sensitive to escape analysis, and the implementation is driven by benchmark.

Let's dig into the commit history. It should help us understand why they're implemented in different way.

#### The initial implementation in [CL 37342](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/sync/+/37342):

1. The draft implementations in the [first patchset](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/sync/+/37342/1/syncmap/map.go#39) are similar:

```golang
func (e *entry) tryStore(i interface{}) bool {
    for {
        p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return false
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, unsafe.Pointer(&i)) {
            return true
        }
    }
}

func (e *entry) tryLoadOrStore(i interface{}) (actual interface{}, loaded, clean bool) {
    for {
        p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return nil, false, false
        }
        if p != nil {
            return *(*interface{})(p), true, true
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, nil, unsafe.Pointer(&i)) {
            return i, false, true
        }
    }
}
```

2. The interface-copying trick was added to both implementation in [patchset 3](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/sync/+/37342/2..3/syncmap/map.go#45):

```
// Copy the interface to make this method more amenable to escape analysis:
// if we hit the "load" path or the entry is expunged, we shouldn't bother
// heap-allocating.
ic := i
```

3. `(*entry).tryStore` is modified to accept a pointer in [patchset 5](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/sync/+/37342/4..5/syncmap/map.go#165):

I can not find a comment on this change. It's most likely a result of the escape analysis and the benchmark tests.

```golang
func (e *entry) tryStore(i *interface{}) bool {
    p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    if p == expunged {
        return false
    }
    for {
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, unsafe.Pointer(i)) {
            return true
        }
        p = atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return false
        }
    }
}

func (e *entry) tryLoadOrStore(i interface{}) (actual interface{}, loaded, ok bool) {
    p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    if p == expunged {
        return nil, false, false
    }
    if p != nil {
        return *(*interface{})(p), true, true
    }

    // Copy the interface after the first load to make this method more amenable
    // to escape analysis: if we hit the "load" path or the entry is expunged, we
    // shouldn't bother heap-allocating.
    ic := i
    for {
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, nil, unsafe.Pointer(&ic)) {
            return i, false, true
        }
        p = atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return nil, false, false
        }
        if p != nil {
            return *(*interface{})(p), true, true
        }
    }
}
```

#### `(*entry).tryStore` was simplified in [CL 137441](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/137441):

The change prevents this escape to heap:

```
sync/map.go:178:26: &e.p escapes to heap
sync/map.go:178:26:     from &e.p (passed to call[argument escapes]) at
```

```golang
func (e *entry) tryStore(i *interface{}) bool {
    for {
        p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return false
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, unsafe.Pointer(i)) {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

#### `(*entry).tryStore` was renamed to `(*entry).trySwap` in [CL 399094](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/399094):

```golang
func (e *entry) trySwap(i *any) (*any, bool) {
   for {
       p := e.p.Load()
       if p == expunged {
           return nil, false
       }
       if e.p.CompareAndSwap(p, i) {
           return p, true
       }
   }
}
```

That's all.

**Note**: some other small CLs are not listed, for example, the [CL 426074](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/426074) that switches the implementation to use `atomic.Pointer`.

Comment: After checking these patch, I may find out why these 2 functions are not implemented in same way.

Comment: I've noticed when a value store in a map by a pointer pointing to it, the value must be allocated in heap.
And only `sync.Map.Swap`, the invoker of trySwap will store a new value in map for sure (the store operation may not in trySwap but it happens any way). Since the value must be in heap from start, it's unecessary to implement it like the other 2 functions.
As `LoadOrStore` and `CompareAndSwap`, they must fullfill their own condition to store a value in map, so the value can be in stack from start and a copy of value can help to reduce some unecessary heap allocation.